# text field showing last character in swift

Tags: xcode, delegates, swift2

I have defined a textfield in storyboard and trying to pass the value to delegate.In my delegate file , I have simple code to retrieve this value :

```
    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

       print("\(textField.text)")
}
```

The issue I am facing is, if I enter 123 , the print out is only 12 . SO basically it prints out till the last character. I am not sure why this is happening. Can I get any inputs?

Answer (score 1):

The delegate method that you've implemented is called **before** each change, to give the delegate the opportunity to reject the change. It follows that the current text of the text field will not have been changed, yet.

You either want to implement `textFieldDidEndEditing()` or, probably better, use the [target-action](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009071-CH3) mechanism to have an action method invoked when the user finishes editing the text field.